# Не компилируется проект с большим файлом в рессурсах

Tags: c#

Добавляю в рессурсы файл меньше 500 метров - проект компилируется.
Если файл несколько больше, при компиляции вылетает компилятор.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Плохо :) Но зачем вам такой огромный файл в ресурсах? Может быть, можно положить его просто рядом с программой?

Comment: Ну такое ТЗ, если бы можно было положить рядом с программой, то я бы и не спрашивал. :)

Comment: тогда упаковывать нужно. Либо побить на мелкие куски. Либо приложить к файлу, но я не уверен, что на шарпе это будет тривиально.

А так, exe размером в пол гига - это же круто и стильно.

Comment: @KoVadim, про упаковку подробнее можно?

Comment: @HondaCbr: Ну так скажите, что целый файл такого размера засунуть невозможно, и дело с концом, пусть правят ТЗ. «Нет» — тоже ответ.

Comment: А это не помогает? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16043010/276994

Comment: @HondaCbr упаковываейте обычным архиватором. тем же zip.

Comment: @KoVadim в общем это так себе вариант...

Comment: Возможно, если бы Вы с самого начала уточнили, зачем такой большой файл, то возможно и решения были бы красивее.

Comment: @KoVadim ну как сказать.. На выходе у нас должен получиться один .exe файл, который распакует несколько файлов объемом около 4 гигабайт.

Comment: тут похоже решается либо задача самораспаковывающегося архива, либо инсталлятора (что в принципе одно и тоже). Может поискать в этом направлении?

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за предложение, но это тоже не вариант)